# Parse.com Overwrites my results when Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

When running the attached code I would expect to see 100 rows inside Parse.com.
Instead, I only see only one.

For some reason, Parse.com is overwriting the same line 100 times.

And ideas? :/

Me.

```
function simplewrite() {

Parse.initialize("********************, ***********************");  

var Numbers = Parse.Object.extend("Numbers");
var numbers = new Numbers();        

for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {

        numbers.set("number", i);

        numbers.save(null, {
          success: function(numbers) {

            console.log("YES " + i);

          },
          error: function(numbers, error) {

            console.log("no! " + i);
            console.log(error);

          }
        });  // End         
};
```

};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop is updating the same `numbers` variable over and over. Try moving the initialization of `numbers` to inside your `for` loop:

```
// ...
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  var numbers = new Numbers();        
// ...
```

Comment: genius! it worked! (I've previously looked at the wrong table) Thanks :)